# What is the angle of a line through the interior and two vertices to one face of an icosahedron?

Tags: analytic-geometry, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

The following diagram represents three faces of a regular icosahedron, flattened out for ease of illustration. If they are folded appropriately, line $ab$, in blue, passes through the interior of the icosahedron. How does one find the angle between the line $ab$ and the plane containing the face $A$?

[image: Three faces of an icosahedron]

(Incidentally, the practical application of this problem is that I need to figure out what angle to set my miter saw to to cut the legs for a decorative table. It would make me happy if I could get the ends of the legs to exactly match the positions of the vertices of a regular icosahedron.)

Answer (score 3):

The result is:

$$\theta=\text{atan}\left(\frac{2}{\Phi+1}\right)\frac{180}{\pi}\approx37.38 \ \text{degrees}$$

where $\Phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 1.618$ is the Golden Ratio, $atan$ is the "arc tan" function (known under the name $\tan^{-1}$ on pocket computers), and factor $\frac{180}{\pi}$ is there for the conversion from radians to degrees.

My computation is based on the following figure which represents a 2D **projection** of the icosahedron **without angle distortion**.

**Proof:** Let $\theta=$ angle $(\vec{AM},\vec{AI})$ and  $\alpha=$ angle $(\vec{AB},\vec{AP}).$

I have used the 3D coordinates of the icosahedron that can be found in
(http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/phi3DGeom.html#section3.5
).

In 2D, coordinates of points $A,B,I$ are $A(0,\Phi), B(\Phi,1), I(1,0)$. Formula (1) results from the following computation:

$$\tan(\theta)=\tan((\alpha+\theta)-\alpha)=\dfrac{\tan(\alpha+\theta)-tan(\alpha)}{1+\tan(\alpha+\theta)tan(\alpha)}$$

$$=\dfrac{(1+\tfrac{1}{\Phi})-(1-\tfrac{1}{\Phi})}{1+(1+\tfrac{1}{\Phi})(1-\tfrac{1}{\Phi})}=\dfrac{\tfrac{2}{\Phi}}{2-\tfrac{1}{\Phi^2}}$$

and the application of relationship $\Phi^2=\Phi+1 \ \iff \ \tfrac{1}{\Phi}=\Phi-1$.

The second picture brings an understanding of the 3D corresponding points.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have added a second picture in order to have a reference wrt to the "real" 3D figure.

Comment: The result can be simplified into the very simple form atan$(3-\sqrt{5})*\tfrac{180}{\pi}$